# g:render form: input fields won't get prefilled

Tags: grails

I'm passing data from my controller with:
controller.groovy

```
render(view: "printme", model: [patient: patient, behandlungInstance: behandlung, frage1Instance: frage1]);
```

to printme.gsp and from printme.gsp with:

```
<g:render contextPath="../frage1" model="['frage1Instance':frage1Instance]" template="form"/>
```

to the frage1/_form.gsp.

When I'm writing

```
render(view: "printme", model: [patient: patient, behandlungInstance: behandlung, frage1Instance: frage1]);
```

everything works and the input fields of "frage1" get prefilled, but when I'm writing

```
 render(view: "printme", model: [patient: patient, behandlungInstance: behandlung, 
        frage1Instance: frage1, frage2Instance: frage2]);
```

the input fields of "frage1" won't get prefilled.

Update:
Example of frage1/_form.gsp

```
    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: frage1Instance, field: 'sub1', 'error')} required">
    <label class="rm_pre" for="sub1">
        <g:message code="frage1.sub1.label_pre" default="Sub1" />
    </label>
    <g:radioGroup name="sub1" values="[-3,-2,-1,1,2,3]" disabled="${session.disabled }" value="${frage1Instance?.sub1}" >
        <span style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px">${it.radio}</span>
    </g:radioGroup>
    <label class="rm_post" for="sub1">
        <g:message code="frage1.sub1.label_post" default="Sub1" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Whats the problem here?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint in the view to see if frage1Instance is populated?

Comment: There may be a bug here, but try to omit model attribute in `g:render` tag inside printme.gsp so frage1Instance is passed as a global, not as a local to the template. Does it work?

Comment: Tomasz, can you give me an example please?

Comment: James, yes its populated. I can write ${frage1Instance.sub1} and see the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The problem was, that the name of some input tags was equal.